# Android EditText delete(backspace) key event

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, key

How can I detect delete (backspace) key event for a editText? I've tried using TextWatcher, but when the editText is empty, when I press delete key, nothing happens. I want to detect delete key press foe an editText even if it has no text.

Comment: There is a similar question in the Stackoverflow. You need to override `EditText` in order to get access to `InputConnection` object which contains `deleteSurroundingText` method. It will help you to detect deletion (backspace) event.  Please, take a look at a solution I provided there [Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34857618/1808829

Answer (score 212, accepted):

NOTE: `onKeyListener` doesn't work for soft keyboards.

You can set `OnKeyListener` for you `editText` so you can detect any key press
EDIT: A common mistake we are checking `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` for `backspace`, but really it is `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` (Really that name is very confusing! )

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //You can identify which key pressed by checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
            //this is for backspace
        }
        return false;       
    }
});
```

Comment: i just tried it, but onKeyListeners apparently do not register backspaces.

Comment: It will not work for soft keyboard. This will only work for hardware input.

Comment: On my Nexus4 (running stock KitKat) this *does* work for the software keyboard.

Comment: As a matter a fact it also works with the soft keyboard on my Samsung Galaxy Xcover (running v2.3.6/Gingerbread)

Comment: what is the way to do for soft keyboards onKeyListener- "@Estel"

Comment: Hi, on my HTC m7 it's work with system keyboard and SwiftKey but doesn't work with new Google Keyboard. I detect also this problem on Samsung S3 and Swype keyboard. Any work solutions for that?

Comment: SO if it doesnt work for soft keys, then why is this answer accepted in/under android platform..

Comment: Confirmed that this does NOT work for soft keyboard in Android 5.1 on Nexus 5.

Comment: use `event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` if you dont want to event to fire twice per press of backspace

Comment: Confirmed working on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge running 6.0.1 and Nexus 5 running 6.0.1

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html , do not use this method to detect soft keyboard key change.

Comment: Use TextWatcher() isntaed https://stackoverflow.com/a/65574180/8663316

Comment: From official Google's documentation `Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this method, although some may elect to do so in some situations.` source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)

Answer (score 94):

It's been a while since you asked but I just had the same issue. As already mentioned by Estel the problem with key listeners is that they only work with hardware keyboards. To do this with an **IME (soft keyboard)**, the solution is a bit more elaborate.

The single method we actually want to override is `sendKeyEvent` in the `EditText`'s `InputConnection` class. This method is called when key events occur in an IME. But in order to override this, we need to implement a custom `EditText` which overrides the `onCreateInputConnection` method, wrapping the default `InputConnection` object in a proxy class! :|

Sounds complicated, but here's the simplest example I could contrive:

```
public class ZanyEditText extends EditText {

    private Random r = new Random();

    public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZanyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setRandomBackgroundColor() {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r
                .nextInt(256)));
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        return new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
                true);
    }

    private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

        public ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
            super(target, mutable);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                ZanyEditText.this.setRandomBackgroundColor();
                // Un-comment if you wish to cancel the backspace:
                // return false;
            }
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }

    }

}
```

The line with the call to `setRandomBackgroundColor` is where my special backspace action occurs. In this case, changing the `EditText`'s background colour.

If you're inflating this from XML remember to use the full package name as the tag:

```
<cc.buttfu.test.ZanyEditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/somefield"
></cc.buttfu.test.ZanyEditText>
```

Comment: I recently ran into the same issue on Jelly Bean.  I found that this solution mostly worked, except that I had to override deleteSurroundingText(...) instead of sendKeyEvent(...) (which was not being called at all).  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: This answer, combined with @Brandon comment above got this working for me. What I'm wondering now is, how this will work on pre-JellyBean devices.

Comment: It does work with the accepted answer on 2.2 and 2.3 devices for me.

Comment: seems like it's firing the key event for backspace twice on 2.3...  :/

Comment: There are two separate bugs affecting the LatinIME keyboard that can prevent generation of KEYCODE_DEL events.  If you read my answer below it will explain what is going on with each of these issues, and how to get around them both.  The solution includes code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard/19980975#19980975

Comment: This solution works really well for me, thank you! But there is one situation in which it does not work - when the user has highlighted text (i.e., getSelectionStart != getSelectionEnd). The sendKeyEvent method is not even called in that situation. I tried the below solution using deleteSurroundingText, but this method is not called if there is a selection either. This is in 4.2. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't work when the edittext is empty, any ideas on how to get an event for the delete key when the edittext is empty and has no text? 4.2

Comment: Any way to bind this only to a specific EditText?

Comment: @jibruno I know this may be a bit late, but it may be that you're getting the event once for key down and once for key up (check event.getAction() for KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).

Comment: Is there any way to get delete key event on gboard handwriting input keyboard. (keyboard with one mic, gear icon and delete key). This method is working fine with gboard and handwriting keyboard.

Answer (score 77):

This is just an addition to Idris's answer, adding in the override to deleteSurroundingText as well. I found more info on that here: [Android: Backspace in WebView/BaseInputConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection)

```
package com.elavon.virtualmerchantmobile.utils;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ZanyEditText extends EditText {

    private Random r = new Random();

    public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZanyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setRandomBackgroundColor() {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r
                .nextInt(256)));
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        return new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
                true);
    }

    private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

        public ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
            super(target, mutable);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                ZanyEditText.this.setRandomBackgroundColor();
                // Un-comment if you wish to cancel the backspace:
                // return false;
            }
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {       
            // magic: in latest Android, deleteSurroundingText(1, 0) will be called for backspace
            if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
                // backspace
                return sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
            }

            return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  The `deleteSurroundingText` bit was exactly what I needed after trying countless other solutions.

Comment: This solution has worked really well for me on previous Android versions, but unfortunately deleteSurroundingText is only called when removing whitespace on 4.4(KitKat). I have tested on both Nexus4 and 7.

Comment: it seems that deleteSurroundingText is required when EditText is multiline. Weird

Comment: Thanks a ton man, didn't work with out deleteSurroundText. Android is so random that they should rename it to androm.

Comment: For me just adding a KeyListener to the ZanyEditText in the enclosing fragment now registers key events.  At least on Android M Preview.  Its also worth noting here that if anyone is trying out this method and is also using the Design Support Library you need to extend AppCompatEditText.  The reason for this is that the Design Support Library automatically replaces all instances of EditText in your layouts with the new version (all done in the background without your knowledge - to help with theme and style), but it can't replace custom classes like this.

Comment: @jibruno hey, I have implemented it, But In my case I have three Edittext, Now How Can I know that "On Which Edittext I have pressed DEL_KEY" ?

Comment: I'll be honest with you @user5716019 I haven't touched android code in 3 years. You should probably open a new question to ask that so you can get some attention on it.

Comment: @jbruno Hi I have implemented the solution you suggested. But apparently I am getting the null pointer crash from this new implementation. Log is as follows

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)

Comment: It works for me, but I can't delete punctuation or spaces anymore!

Comment: It works well for backspace, but when the text is multi-line it makes a copy of text in the previous line on hitting backspace. Any idea ,how to resolve this?

Comment: Man, that helped me so tremendously. I had an ugly solution in place (with invisible character at the start) to detect backspaces at the beginning of a text, but that lead to issues with auto completion etc. This solution is much cleaner -- it does not work with API 19 though, but as Google Keep has the same issue with that version I suppose it is as good as it gets here.

Comment: line '// Un-comment if you wish to cancel the backspace:
                // return false;' is required to uncommented. By default event is being called twice if this does not return false.

Comment: FYI for anybody still using this. After the latest Gboard update (June 25th, 2018), this solution will cause strange behavior when attempting to delete text. Esp if the text has several periods.

Comment: The above code will break for latest Gboard. To make the code workable in old and new Gboard, use `if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0 && ZanyEditText.this.getText().length() == 0) {`

Answer (score 27):

Here is my easy solution, which works for all the API's:

```
private int previousLength;
private boolean backSpace;

// ...

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    previousLength = s.length();
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    backSpace = previousLength > s.length();

    if (backSpace) {

        // do your stuff ...

    } 
}
```

**UPDATE 17.04.18** .
As pointed out in comments, this solution doesn't track the backspace press if EditText is empty (the same as most of the other solutions).
However, it's enough for most of the use cases.
**P.S. If I had to create something similar today, I would do:**

```
public abstract class TextWatcherExtended implements TextWatcher {

    private int lastLength;

    public abstract void afterTextChanged(Editable s, boolean backSpace);

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        lastLength = s.length();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        afterTextChanged(s, lastLength > s.length());
    }  
}
```

Then just use it as a regular TextWatcher:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherExtended() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s, boolean backSpace) {
           // Here you are! You got missing "backSpace" flag
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Do something useful if you wish.
            // Or override it in TextWatcherExtended class if want to avoid it here 
        }
    });
```

Comment: The TextWatcher doesn't trigger on an empty EditText

Comment: this algorithm has a flaw as if you click space after typing then previous length is greater than s.length

Comment: Works as long you don't use selection (autocompletion)

Comment: This will get triggered if you select an autocomplete suggestion

Answer (score 11):

I sent 2 days to find a solution and I figured out a working one :) (on soft keys)

```
public TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
@Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {   } 

@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (count == 0) {
        //Put your code here.
        //Runs when delete/backspace pressed on soft key (tested on htc m8)
        //You can use EditText.getText().length() to make if statements here
        }
    }

@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

After add the textwatcher to your EditText:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

I hope it works on another android devices too (samsung, LG, etc).

Comment: Device HTC desire (HTC is common though :-P )

Comment: if typed one is white space then also count == 0

Comment: That completely doesn't work. count == 0 will be only when edittext is empty!

Comment: @MarcAlexander I am not sure about this answer, however you can check my solution in the answer above

Answer (score 6):

My simple solution which works perfectly. You should to add a flag. My code snippet:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (after < count) {
                isBackspaceClicked = true;
            } else {
                isBackspaceClicked = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!isBackspaceClicked) {
                // Your current code
            } else {
                // Your "backspace" handling
            }
        }
```

Comment: textChangeListner never called on emptTextview.

Answer (score 3):

Example of creating EditText with TextWatcher

```
EditText someEdit=new EditText(this);
//create TextWatcher for our EditText
TextWatcher1 TW1 = new TextWatcher1(someEdit);
//apply our TextWatcher to EditText
        someEdit.addTextChangedListener(TW1);
```

custom TextWatcher

```
public class TextWatcher1 implements TextWatcher {
        public EditText editText;
//constructor
        public TextWatcher1(EditText et){
            super();
            editText = et;
//Code for monitoring keystrokes
            editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                        editText.setText("");
                    }
                        return false;
                }
            });
        }
//Some manipulation with text
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(editText.getText().length() == 12){
                editText.setText(editText.getText().delete(editText.getText().length() - 1, editText.getText().length()));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
            if (editText.getText().length()==2||editText.getText().length()==5||editText.getText().length()==8){
                editText.setText(editText.getText()+"/");
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**for some one who's using Kotlin**

`addOnTextChanged` **is not flexible enought** to handle some cases (ex: detect if user press delete when edit text was empty)

`setOnkeyListener` worked even soft keyboard or hardkeyboard! but **just on some devices**. In my case, it work on Samsung s8 but not work on Xiaomi mi8 se.

if you using kotlin, you can use crossline function `doOnTextChanged`, it's the same as `addOnTextChanged` but callback is triggered even edit text was empty.

NOTE: doOnTextChanged is a part of [Android KTX library](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)

Comment: You might probably specify that `doOnTextChanged ` extension function is accessible in Android KTX library

Comment: But it seems that callback is NOT "triggered even edit text was empty". Could you please provide some snippet with the delete(backspace) interception for empty `EditText`? Thanks in advance

Comment: ah, i have test it when i develop a project. In my case is on xiaomi mi8se, when edittext is empty and you press delete, no callback fired. I'll search for snippet for this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jiff `ZanyEditText` here is `WiseEditText` with `setSoftKeyListener(OnKeyListener)`

```
package com.locopixel.seagame.ui.custom;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper;

public class WiseEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    private Random r = new Random();
    private OnKeyListener keyListener;

    public WiseEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public WiseEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WiseEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        return new MyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
                true);
    }

    private class MyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

        public MyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
            super(target, mutable);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyListener != null) {
                keyListener.onKey(WiseEditText.this,event.getKeyCode(),event);
            }
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {       
            // magic: in latest Android, deleteSurroundingText(1, 0) will be called for backspace
            if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
                // backspace
                return sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
            }

            return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
        }

    }

    public void setSoftKeyListener(OnKeyListener listener){
        keyListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is being called twice for each delete key event.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me :

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (before - count == 1) {
        onBackSpace();
    } else if (s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString().equals("\n")) {
        onNewLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced same issue in Dialog.. because I am using setOnKeyListener.. But I set default return true. After change like below code it working fine for me..

```
    mDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;//this line is important 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that I had custom `Textwatcher`, so I didn't want to add `OnKeyListener` to an `EditText` as well as I didn't want to create custom `EditText`. I wanted to detect if backspace was pressed in my `afterTextChanged` method, so I shouldn't trigger my event.

This is how I solved this. Hope it would be helpful for someone.

```
public class CustomTextWatcher extends AfterTextChangedTextWatcher {

private boolean backspacePressed;

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (!backspacePressed) {
        triggerYourEvent();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
    backspacePressed = count == 0; //if count == 0, backspace is pressed
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested @Jeff's solution on version 4.2, 4.4, 6.0. On 4.2 and 6.0, it works well. But on 4.4, it doesn't work.

I found an easy way to work around this problem. The key point is to insert an invisible character into the content of EditText at the begining, and don't let user move cursor before this character. My way is to insert a white-space character with an ImageSpan of Zero Width on it. Here is my code.

```
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String ss = s.toString();
                    if (!ss.startsWith(" ")) {
                        int selection = holder.editText.getSelectionEnd();
                        s.insert(0, " ");
                        ss = s.toString();
                        holder.editText.setSelection(selection + 1);
                    }
                    if (ss.startsWith(" ")) {
                        ImageSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, 1, ImageSpan.class);
                        if (spans == null || spans.length == 0) {
                            s.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.zero_wdith_drawable)), 0 , 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And we need custom an EditText which has a SelectionChangeListener

```
public class EditTextSelectable extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
public interface OnSelectChangeListener {
    void onSelectChange(int start, int end);
}

private OnSelectChangeListener mListener;

public void setListener(OnSelectChangeListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

...constructors...

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onSelectChange(selStart, selEnd);
    }
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
}
```

}

And the last step

```
holder.editText.setListener(new EditTextSelectable.OnSelectChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectChange(int start, int end) {
                    if (start == 0 && holder.editText.getText().length() != 0) {
                        holder.editText.setSelection(1, Math.max(1, end));
                    }
                }
            });
```

And now, we are done~ We can detect backspace key event when EditText has no actual content, and user will know nothing about our trick.

Answer (score -1):

This question may be old but the answer is really simple using a TextWatcher.

```
int lastSize=0;
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    //2. compare the old length of the text with the new one
    //3. if the length is shorter, then backspace was clicked
    if (lastSize > charSequence.length()) {
        //4. Backspace was clicked
        //5. perform action
    }
    //1. get the current length of of the text
    lastSize = charSequence.length();
}
```

Comment: Much like previous solutions, this can be triggered by autocomplete/suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

Belated but it may help new visitors, use `TextWatcher()` instead will help alot and also it will work for both soft and hard keyboard as well.

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() > 0) {
                    //Here it means back button is pressed and edit text is now empty
                } else {
                   //Here edit text has some text
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: It will not work in every case, Suppose your editText is empty and the user pressed backspace? In that case, nothing will happen with the above solution as no text changed!

Answer (score -3):

You could set a key listener on the activity, and in the callback method, you could detect 
which key the user hit. The code below is for your reference. Hope it helps.

```
//after user hits keys, this method would be called.
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (editText.isFocused()) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:  //delete key
                Log.i("INFO", "delete key hit"); //you should see this log in ddms after you hit delete key
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Checked this solution - KEYCODE_DEL will be thrown to activity only if edit text will not handle this by itself. For example, when there is no text in editText, or there is some text, but cursor is at very beginning.  Thats funny that in my case I need exactly that behavior

Comment: In my activity there is no EditText and I just make the keyboard appear programmatically. I need to catch every soft keyboard key and this seems the only working solution. The other one is overriding the dispatchKeyEvent method. Unfortunately starting from JellyBean the IME doesn't send a KeyEvent for DELETE key. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html