# Android. Backspace/delete key not functioning.

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

When onKeyListener is set Backspace/delete key is not functioning.

I set an OnKeyListener on my EditText. Then default actions of some keys became not functioning. Like DELETE/Backspace. Then I changed to use my own text-deleting function by manipulating the string inside. But it seems to be pretty complex.

I have to get selection, make substring, and so on. Are there other solutions to get the key functioning normally?

Comment: which Android api and device are you using for testing. This is not what usually happens.

Comment: android 2.2 and samsung galaxy

Comment: check the return value of your method

Comment: what method did you mean? onKey? i've set it true.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the IME you are using.
Some IME implements delete function without sending KEYCODE_DEL.
Try other IME than the default.

For example, if you press DEL button long enough, some IME deletes all text in the edit box.
This cannot be done through KEYCODE_DEL.

Comment: indeed i have to write my own text-deleting method to deal with any IME the users use.

Comment: @MRijalulKahfi Do you have an example of how to create your own text-deleting method ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, I solved it by returning false in onKeyListener function. This should execute normal operations on other keys.

```
.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() 
{
     @Override public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
        //your workarounds;
        return false;
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two known issues affecting KEYCODE_DEL for the default (LatinIME) Google Keyboard that ships with Android: Issues 42904 and 62306.

I have researched this and have devised a workaround, with code, that seems to get around both of these issues.  That workaround can be found here:

[Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard/19980975#19980975)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems that you are facing and I somehow managed to stumble on the solution. Apparently, I had setOnKeyListener to 'return true'. After I changed it to 'return false', the phone keyboard works perfect with backspace functioning properly once again on edittext. Hope this helps:

> Solution: One of your existing onkeylistener codes contain 'return true'. Rectify it by setting existing code from 'return true' to 'return false'

```
.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  ...
  return false;
                }
        });
```