# backspace key is not detecting in textwatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-keypad

In `EditText` where I want to add a letter counter. it counts properly but when I entered backspace it's also considered as a letter and count added by 1 which actually should be decremented by 1. my code is

```
text_feedback_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
                                int keyCode = 0;
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                    i--;
                    Log.d("back","backspace pressed"+i);
                }else 
                    i++;
                text_feedback_count.setText(String.valueOf(i) + " / " + String.valueOf(charCounts));
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                text_feedback_count.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
            }
        } 
        );
```

Please help me out when i clicking backspace its not detecting and also not printing on logcat.

Please reply if anybody have some clue.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. TextWatcher is for watching text. 2. seems like you do not understand your own code : you assing 0 to keyCode `int keyCode = 0;` and then compare it to `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` ... i'm pretty sure that  `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL != 0` ... so `i--;` is never called ...

Comment: @Abhishek Karande also if we enter space then also TextWatcher listener not working...any help here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202047/detect-backspace-in-textwatcher

Answer (score 0):

use **OnKeyListener** for you editText so you can detect any key press

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
             //Control comes here when backspace is clicked
             }
    return false        
        }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work on all phones or all input types :(

Comment: Based on what I see here, the comment above makes sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event#comments-4887323

Comment: This should work for hardware keyboards. Keyboard kind is not clear from the question, so I think this answer doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: Though it would be great to point out this limitation.

Comment: if(if(before>count), that mean before change the text was longer than curren, it mean we  delete a letter (or more).