# Detect backspace in TextWatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am using `TextWatcher` and I am unable to detect <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key in `TextWatcher.afterTextChange` event. I also want to clear `textView` on some condition in `textWatcher` event.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // I want to detect backspace key here
}
```

Comment: Code for your `TextWatcher` please ?

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // i want to detect backspace key here 
       
     }

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `KeyListener` can fulfil both of your conditions.

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
             //on backspace
             }
    return false        
        }
});
```

Similarly inside the `onKey()`, you can put multiple check statements to check for the condition, when you would want to clear the `textView`.

**EDIT :** As *@RankoR* was kind enough to point out, please bear in mind that **`onKeyListener()` works only for the hardware keyboards** and not the soft keyboards.

Comment: OnKeyListener works only for HW keyboards.

Comment: @RankoR : Yes, I am aware of the fact the onKeyListener does not work for the soft-keyboard. But if you went through the question once again, you would see that the question is not specific for the soft-keyboard. But, yes..then again, you have made a pretty much valid point. Will edit my answer to include your point.

Comment: @RankoR  :Edited the answer. Maybe you can reconsider your *downvote* now. :D

Comment: Now, that is really considerate of you! Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: This doesnt work on Android 4.1

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will look into the matter and see if I can get something to work. Or do you already have a solution for 4.1..?

Answer (score 20):

To detect a backspace in `TextWatcher`, you can check the variable count that is passed into the `onTextChange` function (count will be 0 if a backspace was entered), like this:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

  if (react) {
    if (count == 0) {
      //a backspace was entered
    }

    //clear edittext
    if(/*condition*/) {
      react = false;
      setText("");
      react = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The react `boolean` is needed for the `setText`() function otherwise it becomes recursive. Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't give a call back when there will be no text change that is when s.length() = 0, what ever key is pressed there will be no call back..

Comment: There is no callback received in `onTextChanged` when back button is pressed and there is no character in the `EditText`. Not sure why this answer even exits here!

Comment: if typed one is white space then also count == 0