# Text Watcher to detect backspace and white space in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, backspace, android-textwatcher

Is there option to detect `EditText` input is white space or backspace. I want to get to know if user enter something in between already typed words.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Comment: use this link  :-    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202047/detect-backspace-in-textwatcher

Comment: but it will not work for soft key board

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setOnKeyListener` to detect back space key is pressed by user:

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       switch(keyCode){
              case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
                   //on backspace
       }  

return false        
    }
});
```

and to detect space between words use `TextWatcher`:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String c = String.valueOf(s);
            if(c.equals(" ")){
                //backspace pressed

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of c.equals(" ") you have to use c.contains(" ");