# Backspace doesn't work properly when TextWatcher is used

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, backspace

I needed to format money values entered into an `EditText` so I used a `TextWatcher` but now I have issues with backspace in soft keyboard.

Normally if you **hold** the **backspace** key in the keyboard, it **keeps removing characters** in `EditText` until there is nothing left. After adding the `TextWatcher`, you need to **manually press** the backspace button **many times** in order to completely get rid of all characters as **holding it no longer works**.

***How do I fix it?***

```
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final EditText et;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et) {
        this.et = et;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            String originalString = s.toString();

            long longval;
            if (originalString.contains(",")) {
                originalString = originalString.replaceAll(",", "");
            }
            longval = Long.parseLong(originalString);

            DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
            formatter.applyPattern("#,###,###,###");
            String formattedString = formatter.format(longval);

            //setting text after format to EditText
            et.setText(formattedString);
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [`afterTextChanged(Editeable s)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) documents, any change happened on this `EditText` will be notified from this callback AND it's obvious that this callback lock back-space callback in order to get advantage of reformatting the text as you need  `"#,###,###,###"`

**Propper fix:** You need to proceed with your code [only and only if the input wasn't the backspace key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202047/detect-backspace-in-textwatcher/12202133#12202133), i.e:

```
   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (after < count) {
            isBackspaceClicked = true;
        } else {
            isBackspaceClicked = false;
        }
    }

  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!isBackspaceClicked) {
            // Your current code
        }
     }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? What is the fix then?