# Ignore backspace in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that I need to ignore <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keyEvents. I have the following class, but it doesn't work:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText    {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
                    //do nothing
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tru to use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK in place of KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method instead of adding a listener

Comment: this works if the field is empty, but otherwise the event never reaches the onKeyDown method

Answer (score 1):

Try returning false here: `if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){

                    return false;
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Chedk out the `InputFilter`, it can probably do this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/614231

I have used the `InputFilter` to do other types of filtering on the input, but I'm not sure if you can actually use it to prevent the backspace character or not.