# How to implement a PIN INPUT style screen using 12-keys keyboard Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Here is my problem. I have 4 EditTexts and i want them to behave like a pin system:

- Whenever a letter is digited to the edittext it moves automatically to the next one (implemented using an TextWatcher).
- Whenever the backspace key is pressed and the current eddittext is empty it removes the text from the previous edittext (implemented according to this answer [Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event/11377462#11377462)).

I was able to implement this system, but the system does not work using a 12-keys soft keyboard, since there are more than one letter per key. 
The user only can use the first letter of each key because the TextWatcher for each EditText whenever an input is made automatically passes to the next EditText.

Does anyone have an idea of how can i parse this kind of input from a 12-key keyboard, of it there is any function in android that forces the user to use a full keyboard?

Any help would be helpful. :)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `inputType="number"` as EditText xml attribute to force the right keyboard.

Comment: That does not resolves my problem, since i want letters also in the pin. The only solution I was able to find was create my own keyboard.