# Android Soft Keyboard 'Delete' will not trigger OnKeyListener for all IME types or phones

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am looking for a solution to detect Delete events from the Soft Keyboard.  Currently, onKeyListeners do not catch Delete/backspace in the numeric keypad for all phones or IME types.

Problem: I have 10 EditText fields.  Each represent a digit in a phone number. When a number gets entered into each field, the focus changes to the next in line. 
However, if the user needs to backspace, they have to focus on each field and then hit delete.  It would be nice if when focus was on either an empty field or the last field in the series, delete would delete the digit in the previous field so that the user can then enter a new value.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please paste some code if you've tried anything yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event)

Comment: onKeyUp, onKeyDown, onKeyListener simply do not catch a delete event.