# How to detect whether user is just pressing backspace (delete) key in SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a custom autocomplete function that fetches results from a remote server in the `onQueryTextChange` method based on the input. It is similar to JQuery autocomplete plugin that fetches results via Ajax on keyup listener.

However it is quite a waste to fetch results when the user is just pressing `backspace` to delete the input text he has previously entered because the returned results are usually the same in my situation. How can I prevent that from happening?

I have tried using a global boolean variable `backKeyPressed` to detect whether the user is pressing `backspace` and check it in `onQueryTextChange` but `setOnKeyListener` doesn't even work at all. No logs for "onKey" have even been shown in the logcat.

Would anyone have any ideas on how to detect if backspace key is pressed in  `onQueryTextChange`?

```
private boolean backKeyPressed = false;
private Runnable autoCompleteRunnable;
private Handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private String enteredSuggestion = "";

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /****************/

    searchView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        backKeyPressed = true;
                    }else{
                        backKeyPressed = false;
                    }
                    Log.d("onKey",Boolean.toString(backKeyPressed));
                    return false;
                }
            });

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    /**Some functions**/
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String inputText) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(autoCompleteRunnable);

                    if(enteredSuggestion.trim().equals(inputText.trim())){
                       Log.d("response_on_duplicated","true");
                       return false;
                    }

                    if(backKeyPressed == true){
                        Log.d("response_onKey","No");
                        return false;
                    }
                    autoCompleteRunnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            fetchSuggestionFromRemoteServer(inputText);
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(autoCompleteRunnable, 3000);

                    enteredSuggestion = inputText;

                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: if the user presses the backspace usually you should get the more results, is'n it? so whats the reason in that?

Comment: Are you using soft keyboards? because OnKeyListener doesn't work on it.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/4886858/2252016

Comment: @1binary0, ah yes, I'm using soft keyboards

Comment: @pskink,Thanks, I would think about it. Does ACTV require building a list of suggestions beforehand? I have about a thousand entries in the remote database. My current approach only fetches five entries at a time based on the user's input.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)

Comment: with this approach you can cache returned data from `runQuery` to use it for future requests when you expect no data changes, note that when you type quite fast it is not called every time the `ACTV` input changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get the backspace key. You could use a simple work around.

You could store the `length` of your query string when a server call is made.
Then next time in `onQueryTextChange` you can check whether the length of `inputText` is less than the length of server call string. If it is less then update the server call length with this new length, because if you don't next time if a user removes 2 characters and adds a 1 new character, your code will not make a server call. If you want a pseudo-code, do let me know.

Comment: I have quickly added some code based on your suggestion. See  variable `enteredSuggestion` which is used to store the previous input value. If it is the same as the current input value, it will not make a server call. Next I'll work on comparing the lengths of them. Just a rough idea. Please feel free to give me some suggestions.

Comment: Yes that's great! Just one thing, in your `onQueryTextChange`, you have used this assignment. `enteredSuggestion = itemTitle;`. Shouldn't it be `enteredSuggestion = inputText;`?