# EditText changedListener is not getting called

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

I use an `EditText` to filter some values in an `ListView`.

It works so far, but I have one problem. First my code:

```
final EditText mEditText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String mFilter = editable.toString();
        mListViewUpdater.setFilter(mFilter);
        Log.d("Editable", editable.toString());
    }
}
```

The method `afterTextChanged()` gets called when I type something in and the filter is applied and works.

But if I delete everything in the `EditText`, the `ListView` stays at it last filtered state until I close the keyboard and then it shows all values again.

Is there a way to show all values eevn if the EditText is empty but the Keyboard is not collapsed?

Best regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put all of your code into the `onTextChanged()` method instead of the `afterTextChanged()` method.