# How to detect backspace press on custom Entry in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I've made a custom entry control in Xamarin forms PCL. I can get **TextChanged** event with new and old Values without any problem (when entering for example digits or letters). The problem's that when I want to catch a 'backspace' on empty entry control when it's focused it simply does not trigger TextChanged event. I've found **Complete** event for an entry which is able to catch 'Enter' key press but there's nothing for delete/backspace. Do you have any ideas how to do that? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not to use TextChanged because if your Entry is empty you have no event fired.

Android should use setOnKeyListener to catch if a key is pressed, but it seems that it works only for hardware keyboard (and some soft keyboard)...

I think you can take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event) and try to create a custom renderer in C#

Comment: Thanks for answer but creating custom renderer for this one is just waste of time. Take a look at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html  . Not some of the soft keyboard, but only hardware.