# Android - setOnKeyListener only works if I hold the button

Tags: android, kotlin, focus, adapter, onkeylistener

Well, I got an `EditText` on my `adapter` that I want to clear his focus when I press button back of the soft-key bar. But the problem is: it just works if I hold that button and not when I make it quickly. What am I supposed to do? Here's the code:

```
holder.comprimento.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          v.clearFocus()
          return@OnKeyListener true
     }
     false
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL instead of KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.

```
 holder.comprimento.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
      v.clearFocus()
      return@OnKeyListener true
 }
 false
 })
```

UPDATE
KeyEvent will be triggered only with softkeyboard.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener

Comment: Nop, doesn't work. I think keycode is not a problem.

Comment: Key event will be triggered only for hard keyboard. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener

Comment: So what I should use?

Comment: Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event