# Unable to remove text from EditText field when adding dash on text change listener

Tags: android, android-layout, textwatcher

I am appending "-" in edittext when text length is `3 or 7` .

Following is my code.

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(editable.length() == 3 || editable.length() == 7){
                editable.append("-");
            }
```

This works fine, and adds "-", but when i try to remove some text, it stuck on these places, so if i enter `221-` and then i press backspace it does not work, and does not allow me to remove these characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you press backspace with `221-`, you are removing the `-` character which gives you `221`. But in your text changed listener, it appends another `-` since you're left with 3 characters so your text becomes `221-` again. Therefore you're going in a loop. You should perform the text formatting at the end to avoid this. Or you can add another listener to detect when backspace is pressed.

See this link for more details 
[Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event)