# Detect delete key on empty input field for mobile devices?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, input, mobile

Somehow the `OnValueChanged()` method doesn't get called when an user presses the **delete key** on an **empty android mobile Inputfield**.

I guess as it is empty the value of inputfield is `""` before pressing delete and still `""` after. Thus there isn't an `OnValueChanged()` called.

I tried checking for the `delete key` in `Update()` but Android doesn't seem to notify an application when the `delete key` gets pressed.

How can I check if the delete key is pressed?

---

What I want to achieve is that the `Inputfield` gets **deactivated** when the user presses the **delete key** and the **inputfield is empty**...

---

Using **c#** and **Unity**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As getting an actual `KeyEvent` from Android for the `delete key` seems to be *quite complicated*, I managed to do an **easy workaround**.

Simply set the `text` of the `Inputfield` **on activation** to `" "` (*Simply space*).
That way when the user presses the `delete key`, the space gets deleted and `OnValueChanged` gets called.

To avoid problems with the additional space in the input, you can simply implement a method that erases the space when more input is typed.

Comment: It works, but it's hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with C languages, I work with Java and Kotlin. In Java development, the implementation of the solution would look like this:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
            //this is for backspace
        }
        return false;       
    }
});
```

Answer taken from this page: [Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event)

I hope this helps you

Comment: I already did the equivalent in c# but as mentioned in the question it seems like android doesn't notify the application when the delete key gets pressed

Comment: @unitydevelopmentquestions
Listening to backpress clicks and Listening text changes in the input field
 are handling by different methods. It might be worth making sure you are using the correct one.

This one that you described looks like TextWatcher.onEditTextChanged. And it's really doesn't notify then InputField is empty